# How do I correctly call refreshToken in GCM for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrated my app with GCM, and it is on the store and it works fine. Now I want to refresh the registration tokens and send new tokens to my server.

GCM provides a method called `refreshToken`:

```
func onTokenRefresh() {
  GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)   
}
```

I called this method from my `ApplicationBecomeActive`. This calls the method:

```
func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
  if (registrationToken != nil) {
  } else {
    print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
  }
}
```

But I am not getting a `registrationToken`. Every time it says:

> Registration to GCM failed with error "registration to GCM failed with
>   error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error
>   1001.)"

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift), to refresh the registration token, the `GGLInstanceIDDelegate` protocol declares an onTokenRefresh method that is called when the system determines that tokens need to be refreshed.

**Registration to GCM failed with error "registration to GCM failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 1001.)"** error occurs when your server is under load and not responding to requests before the HTTP(s) code gives up. Sounds like you have a configuration problem to address.

Check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2314).